# Setting array length as variable value?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I was wondering if it's possible to set an array's length as a variable value as it would help a lot with my current function.

Essentially what I want to be able to do is:

```
q = 2
Dim AnswerIDs(q)
```

However, this results in an error, does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q = 2
Dim AnswerIDs()
Redim AnswerIDs(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```vb
q = 2
Dim AnswerIDs(), i
ReDim AnswerIDs(-1)
i = 0
Do While q > i
  ReDim Preserve AnswerIDs(UBound(AnswerIDs) + 1)
  AnswerIDs(UBound(AnswerIDs)) = "test"
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: What syntax is that, it certainly isn't [tag:vbscript] can you even use `ReDim AnswerID(-1)` like that and what is with `i++` this isn't [tag:c#] or [tag:javascript].